# Basic queries regarding Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, data-science

I am working Convolutional Neural Network and comparing it other methods such as HoG.

After completing the binary classification with both these methods, I got these results:

**HoG method:**

Training Accuracy: 83%
Testing Accuracy: 62%

**CNN method:**

Training Accuracy: 100%
Validation Accuracy: 91%
Testing Accuracy: 85%

My question is, any these methods have over fitting in training?

Comment: Would be better to suggest algorithm based on the needs not on the results ?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by that? I am not suggesting at the moment. my question is about the over fitting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods show overfitting, which you actually cannot totally avoid. The key is to bring it down to a minimum. I'm not very familiar with HoG, but for the CNNs there are a couple of common ways to minimize overfitting, such as drop out, batch normalization, early stopping and cross validation. And of course good data, meaning a lot data to train on that is as diverse as possible.

It is also always a good idea to visualize the training progress over the training epochs: training and testing accuracy next to the respective loss functions. The loss will get smaller for both at the beginning, but eventually the testing loss will increase. That is the point where you should stop training, since all further effort will only lead in a better training accuracy. The CNN learns the training samples by heart, figuratively speaking. 100% accuracy on training samples suggests that happened in your case.

Comment: what I understand from your answer is the training and testing accuracy should be same?

Comment: no, that is not what I meant. However, you could try to minimize their difference using the above mentioned techniques.

Comment: Yes I have tried with the dropout and the different between training and testing is about 12%.. is there something like gap shouldn't be much than 15-20% etc?

Comment: Well, in the end all what matters is how well your model performs on unseen data, i.e. the testing data. There is no general rule how big the difference between training and testing accuracy should be. However, a big difference hints overfitting. This is potentially bad, since the model weights each training samples unique features more than the more general features that actually separate the classes and therefore misclassifies the testing data. This can happen, if your model is overly complex for the amount of training data you have at hand. So you could experiment with less complex models.

Comment: note that it is hard to give specified suggestions without any information about your problem. Just experiment with different models and parameters, think about reducing the learning rate over time, take a look at the training statistics, try to increase the number of samples, if possible. Just get a feeling for CNNs, experience how they react if you do this or that.

Comment: nice, I like the description that "CNN learns the training samples by heart" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the models show overfitting (a huge gap between training and testing accuracies). There are countless strategies for overfitting these days. You should try them first. I also would suggest you to shuffle the dataset well enough before use, since sometimes similar images can go to the training set and prevent the model to generalise well. In other words, training images would be 'easier' than the test images.

Comment: agree, sometimes the training dataset is not representative of the population (overall) dataset

Answer (score 0):

Both models display similar results, which is a symptom for overfitting:

- Training accuracy = high
- Testing accuracy = lower

Overfitting happens when a model learns the details and noise in the training data so much that it negatively impacts the performance of the model on new data. This means that the noise or random fluctuations in the training data is picked up and learned as reality (real data) by the model. The problem is that these noise data are not applicable to new data and so models are unable to generalize.

I find [this article](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/overfitting) explains quite well, you can have a look.